# Sql CE 3.5: Probelma na geração do DataContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-phone, connectionstring

## Ao tentar gerar o DataContext a um projeto WindowsPhone 8.1, por meio da interface do SQL Server Compact toolbox em:

-Generate Code (EF/LINQ to SQL/SyncFX)  >>   Add Windows Phone DataContext to current Project (needs 3.5)http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC727449.png).

É apresentando a mensagem:

*The selected project type does not support Windows Phone 7.18.0 – wrong Target framework moniker Windows Phone app version= 8.1.*

**Não esta permitindo gerar o datacontext para meu projeto Windows Phone 8.1;**

O que devo fazer para adicionar o meu banco.sdf como datacontex do meu projeto ?

Comment: a versão do .net utilizada é a 3.5?

Comment: 3.5 é a versão do SQL Server compact, também tentei fazendo uso da versão 4.0 do SQL Server CE mas não tive exito

Comment: você está tentando usar EF? Ele não funciona a não ser que seja a versão 7.0

Comment: I you are using the add-in, make sure to have the latest refresh by uninstalling and reinstalling from Extension and Updates or from VS gallery!

Answer (score 1):

O EF requer o System.Data.dll que atualmente não é suportado pelo Windows Phone...
Oque é suportado atualmente é o Linq to SQL que funciona igual o estilo de ORM do EF.

Main informações [Neste Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202872(v=vs.105).aspx)

Acredito que a [versão 7](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki) terá suporte.